# Form value creates a URL

Tags: html, forms, url

I am trying to create a very simple form with a little bit of extra code to get the results as described below: the problem is I don't know how to go about doing it.

What I am trying to achieve:

I have a form which has one text input box with the name 'url'. I want the user to be able to input a number into the box. When the user submits the form they should be redirected to a new website. The new website's URL will be based on the number inputted into the form.

The first part of the URL will always be: http://name.com/

Then the number that the user inputted will be attached to the end. So if 123456 is entered into the form then on submission of the form the user would be taken to http://name.com/123456

How can I get this working? I am guessing it will require JavaScript or something.

Comment: This does require some programming - either client side using Javascript, or server side using one of many server side technologies.

Comment: In javascript you would grab the current URL, the value input and simply redirect to a newly constructed URL from them - it is not complicated.

Comment: @oded Its not complicated if you know the answer. Clearly i don't else i wouldn't be asking. For someone with such a high reputation on this site your answer was not entirely helpful. Everyone has to learn from someone or somewhere....

Comment: It is not an answer - it is a comment. I agree that one needs to learn from somewhere, but this question doesn't detail any of effort you have put into finding an answer - code, notions etc... We _do_ expect some effort and evidence of that effort from those who ask questions - Stack Overflow is not a "give me teh codez" kind of site.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<script>
    function process()
    {
        var url = "http://name.com/" + document.getElementById("url").value;
        location.href = url;
        return false;
    }
</script>

<form onSubmit="return process();">
    URL: <input type="text" name="url" id="url">
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

Comment: keep in mind that this wont submit other data such as _GET or _POST data along with the form.

Answer (score 8):

You can add `onsubmit="this.action='http://google.com/'+this.fieldName.value;"` to your  tag.

Comment: This one is the cleanest, but needs some clarification. In the case of the initial poster, it should be something like ```<form onsubmit="this.action = 'http://name.com/' + this.url.value;">```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function goToPage() {
        var page = document.getElementById('page').value;
        window.location = "http://name.com/" + page;
    }
</script>
<input type="text" id="page" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="goToPage();" />
```