# Cannot read property 'value' of null Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

My Code:

```js
var cat, inputdat;
var KeyUrl = "someurl";
cat = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];
var fLen = cat.length;

for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {

  inputdat += "<label for=\"" + cat[i] + "\">" + cat[i] + "</label><br><input type=\"text\" id=\"" + cat[i] + "\" name=\"" + cat[i] + "\" value=\"\"" + cat[i] + "\"><br><a href=\"" + KeyUrl + document.getElementById(cat[i]).value + "\" rel=\"nofollow\">Here</a><br>";

}
inputdat += "<br/>";
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = inputdat;
```

```html
<h2 id="res">hello</h2>
```

The error:

> ````
> {
>  "message": "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null",
>  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
>  "lineno": 19,
>  "colno": 202
> }```
> ````

Part of the code causing the error:

```
href=\""+KeyUrl+document.getElementById(cat[i]).value+"
```

I am trying to append the value of the input to my keyurl but I am getting null.

Comment: what is null? what is fLen? did u declare inputdat?

Comment: By default input values are `null` so you probably want to check that the input isn't `null`

Comment: Does your document have `cat[i]` selector on any element? Try logging the value of `cat[i]` to see if you have the right selector

Comment: check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967338/how-to-append-to-an-html-form-url-from-a-post-request

Comment: @AbrarHossain once i removed the ```document.getElementById(cat[i]).value``` and using chrome console i got the value using same code

Comment: Is the script in the head of the document or at the bottom of the body?

Comment: without seeing whatever `cat` is, and without seeing the html, its pretty impossible to know what's going on outside of a null input value

Comment: which browser is the code not working?

Comment: try to debug using developer console

Comment: what is null? inputDat is null? cat[I] is null?

Comment: `cat[i]` will never equal `"res"`, and so the `document.getElementById(cat[i])` will never find a match

Comment: it's null because it's yet generated. it has to be rendered before document.getElementById can get the value.

Comment: @holtc _"By default input values are `null`"_ - That's not true. The `value` attribute of an empty `<input />` element will return an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there isn't an element with `id` `abc`, or the rest of the array `cat`.

You should run a loop that iterates through `cat` and checks if there is an element with `ID` `cat[i]`. Here is how that looks:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
    if(!document.getElementById(cat[i])) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = cat[i];
        div.setAttribute("value", `alert('this is a test: ${i+1}')`);
        document.body.appendChild(div);

    }
}
```

The line `document.getElementById(cat[i])` returns `null` because there is no element with such an ID, but the above code should fix that. Here is how I tested the code, if that will help:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<h2 id="res">hello</h2>


<script type="text/javascript" defer>
var cat, inputdat;
inputdat = "";
var KeyUrl = "javascript:"; // CHANGE THIS URL, IT IS JUST AN EXAMPLE
cat = ["abc","def","ghi"];
var fLen = cat.length;


for (var i = 0; i < cat.length; i++) {
    if(!document.getElementById(cat[i])) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = cat[i];
        div.setAttribute("value", `alert('this is a test: ${i+1}')`);
        document.body.appendChild(div);

    }
}




for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {

    console.log(cat[i]);
    
    inputdat += `<label for="${cat[i]}">${cat[i]}</label><br><input type="text" id="${cat[i]}" name="${cat[i]}" value="${cat[i]}"><br><a href="${KeyUrl+document.getElementById(cat[i]).getAttribute("value")}" rel="nofollow">Here</a><br>`;


    inputdat += "<hr/>";
    
}

document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = inputdat;
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes - there isn't an element with the `ID`s in the array. That is why when the script tries to find `#abc`, `#def`, or `#ghi` it returns `null`, which obviously does not hold the property "`value`"